# How to get my login button to work in my navigation bar with the following css code

Tags: html, css

I have the following navigation menu and for some reason, my login buttons won't work unless I use position: sticky. If I sticked with position:relative, it would be contained in that nav section and won't be clickable, is there a way to get around this if I want to keep the login button there?

Is there also a way to do a diagram with 3 lines? I have seen something liked that in some other websites where they have a box with 3 horizontal lines...

```
    /* null margins and padding to give good cross-browser baseline */
html,body,address,blockquote,div,
form,fieldset,caption,
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,
hr,ul,li,ol,ul,dl,dt,dd,
table,tr,td,th,p,img {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

img, fieldset {
    border:none;
}

hr {
    display:none;
    /*
        HR in my code are for semantic breaks in topic/section, NOT
        style/presenation, so hide them from screen.css users
    */
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
    /*
        Some older small screen devices will try to force a text-size
        adjustment regardless of our viewport meta, this overrides that
        so it obeys what we tell it. This is in a max-width query so that
        we don't send this to desktop safari, as it breaks zooming there...
        Even though it does NOT break zooming in mobile Safari?

        Way to herpa that derp there Apple!
    */
    * {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
        -ms-text-size-adjust:none;
    }
}

body {
    font:normal 85%/150% arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
}

table, input, select, textarea, button {
    font:normal 100%/150% arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    padding:0.5em 1.25em 0.5em 0.5em;
    /* larger right padding makes room for mobile/touch icon */
    font:normal 200%/150% arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
}

#mainMenuShowHide {
    /*
        We want to hide this for screen layout, but if we set it to display:none
        the label won't check/uncheck this input. Sliding it off screen does
        the same job without breakign the functionality.
    */
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;
}

#mainMenu {
    position:relative;
    /* make sure this is higher than all other elements on the page! */
    z-index:999; 
    padding:0 1em 1em;
}

#mainMenu,
#mainMenu ul {
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#mainMenu li {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:inline-block;
    width:14em;
    margin:0 0.2em 0.8em;
    vertical-align:top;
    -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
    page-break-inside:avoid;
    break-inside:avoid;
}

#mainMenu li li {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:0.25em;
}

#mainMenu li:hover {
    overflow:visible;
    z-index:999;
}

#mainMenu a {
    display:block;
    padding:0.25em 2em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#008;
    background:#FFF;
    border:0.125em solid #CCC;
    border-radius:0.5em;
}

#mainMenu a:active,
#mainMenu a:focus,
#mainMenu li:hover a:hover {
    background:#FF0;
}

#mainMenu li:hover > a {
    background:#CFC;
}


#mainMenu ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-0.2125em; /* parent's border width */
    top:2.25em; /* 1.5 line-height + 2 * ( 0.125 border + 0.25 padding ) */
    width:100%;
    padding-top:0.25em;
}

#mainMenu ul ul {
    left:14em;
    top:0;
    padding:0 0 0 0.25em;
}

#mainMenu a.hasKids:before {
    content:"\25BC";
    position:absolute;
    right:0.25em;
    top:0.3125em;
}

#mainMenu ul a.hasKids:before {
    content:"\25B6";
}

#mainMenuShowHide + label {
    position:absolute;
    top:0.667em;
    right:0.667em;
    width:1.5em;
    padding:0.25em 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:150%;
    background:#FFF;
    border:0.125em solid #CCC;
    border-radius:0.5em;
}

#mainMenuShowHide + label:before {
    content:"\1F446";
}

#mainMenuShowHide:checked + label:before {
    content:"\1F401"
}

#mainMenuShowHide + label:after {
    content:"Switch to expanded menu";
    position:absolute;
    top:0.5em;
    right:3em;
    width:14em;
    text-align:right;
    font:normal 66.67%/120% arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
}

#mainMenuShowHide:checked + label:after {
    content:"Switch to dropdown menu";
}

#mainMenuShowHide:checked ~ #mainMenu {
    columns:4;
    padding-top:1em;
    border:solid #CCC;
    border-width:0.2em 0;
}

#mainMenuShowHide:checked ~ #mainMenu li {
    display:block;
    overflow:visible;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#mainMenuShowHide:checked ~ #mainMenu ul {
    position:static;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    padding:0 0 0 1em;
}

#mainMenuShowHide:checked ~ #mainMenu a {
    border:0;
    padding:0.5em; /* keep large for finger-sized targets */
    margin-bottom:0.25em;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#mainMenuShowHide:checked ~ #mainMenu a.hasKids:before {
    content:"";
}

@media (max-width:77em) {
    #mainMenu {
        display:none;
    }
    #mainMenuShowHide:checked ~ #mainMenu {
        display:block;
    }
    #mainMenuShowHide + label {
        border:0.2em solid #000;
    }
    #mainMenuShowHide + label:after,
    #mainMenuShowHide + label:before,
    #mainMenuShowHide:checked + label:after,
    #mainMenuShowHide:checked + label:before {
        content:"";
        position:static;
        display:block;
        width:auto;
        height:0.2em;
        margin:0 0.2em;
        font-size:100%;
        border:solid #000;
        border-width:0.2em 0;
    }
    #mainMenuShowHide:checked + label {
        background:#FF0;
    }
    #mainMenuShowHide + label:after,
    #mainMenuShowHide:checked + label:after {
        border-top:0;
    }
}

@media (max-width:70em) {
    #mainMenuShowHide:checked ~ #mainMenu {
        columns:3;
    }
}

@media (max-width:48em) {
    #mainMenuShowHide:checked ~ #mainMenu {
        columns:2;
    }
}

@media (max-width:26em) {
    #mainMenuShowHide:checked ~ #mainMenu {
        columns:1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also have the following code underneathe the above code but can't get my header .nav-login {} to work:

Comment: just edit your question and paste in the html as you did with css :)